# creating backbone model error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am begginer in backbone.js
When I  cretaing a model with data , I have  error.

firstly a declared model as following;

```
var verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp = {
    Models :{},
    Collections : {},
    Views :{},
    Templates :{}
}

///BackBone model setting;
     verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = new Backbone.Model.extend({
         initialize: function(){}
     });
```

then I create a model as following,

```
    var journey = {"key": "0T", "carrier": "PS", "carrierName": "Ukraine International Airlines", "flight_number": "102", "origin": "AMS", "destination": "KBP", "departure_time": "2013-08-18T13:10:00.000+02:00", "arrival_time": "2013-08-18T16:55:00.000+03:00"}


var JourneyModel = new verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey(journey);
```

In this line , I have error like "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply' "

I cant find a solution  why I get such error.

regards ,

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke `new` on `Backbone.Model.extend` when defining your `Journey` model. Do this:

```
 verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object here:

```
 verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = new Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){}
 });
```

Change it to:

```
 verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line,

```
    var JourneyModel = new verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey(journey);
```

try following line:

```
    var JourneyModel = verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey.set(journey);
```

and also instead of

```
    verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = new Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){}
 });
```

write like

```
   verifiedBookPriceSolutionApp.Models.Journey = new Backbone.Model;
```